# setting different imageview of expandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hello everyone I worked with this tutorial for `ExpandableListView` with checkboxes: [link to tutorial](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html).

Subsequently I needed the same example but instead of checkboxes I have to put the ImageView I got to do it but the problem that I do not want every child will have the same images, so I have not found how to pictures of each child in each group of expandable list!
if anyone can help me!